# CircleCI ignores git tag filters

Tags: git, continuous-integration, circleci

I'd like to test each commit (workflow "test"). In case the commit is tagged and on a certain branch, deployment should be triggered (workflow "test-n-deploy").
Therefore, I created the following workflow:

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  test:
    jobs:
      - test-py36-yml
  test-n-deploy:
    jobs:
      - test-py36-yml:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/
      - test-deploy-pypi:
          requires:
            - test-py36-yml
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/
            branches:
              only:
                - test_deployment_pypi
                - test_deployment_script
```

The complete script can be found here: https://github.com/kipoi/kipoi/blob/test_deployment_pypi/.circleci/config.yml

**My problem:**
CircleCI completely ignores the tag filters. Even if the commit is untagged, it runs the whole `test-n-deploy` workflow.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#executing-workflows-for-a-git-tag? Your config doesn't seem to match what you're describing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe In which manner? If you check the CI logs (https://circleci.com/gh/kipoi/kipoi), you can see that job #2914 correctly runs the "test" workflow, while jobs #2915 and #2916 wrongly run "test-n-deploy" for the untagged commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CircleCI filter does not combine both filters, it is like an "or" statement.
In your case, even though you've filtered tags, `test-deploy-pypi` will run if it will be in one of the branches you've filtered: `test_deployment_pypi` or `test_deployment_script`.

In order to make it work only for tags, you'll have to ignore those branches:

```
  filters:
    branches:
      ignore: /.*/
    tags:
      only: /v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/
```

Notice that I've also changed tags filter to have "v" at the begining, since tags add it automatically unless you override it. 
If you do change the tag name from the default one, change it back to your regex.